Mobile Dependency Resolver / Gradle Errors
I'm unable to resolve any packages with Mobile Dependency Resolver from within Unity.
Unity 6
MacOS
Android
Running Gradle...

/Users/tsukasa/Desktop/GitHub/test-project/Temp/PlayServicesResolverGradle/gradlew --daemon -b "/Users/tsukasa/Desktop/GitHub/test-project/Temp/PlayServicesResolverGradle/PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" "-PANDROID_HOME=/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/6000.0.16f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=/Users/tsukasa/Desktop/GitHub/test-project/Assets/Plugins/Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=file:////Users/tsukasa/Desktop/GitHub/test-project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository;https://android-sdk.is.com/;https://maven.google.com/" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:0.11.01;com.ironsource:adqualitysdk:7.20.0;com.ironsource.unity:adqualitysdk:7.20.0;com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:8.3.0;com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1;com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0;com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.2.0;com.ironsource.adapters:admobadapter:4.3.44;com.ironsource.adapters:unityadsadapter:4.3.42;com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.12.2" "-PUSE_JETIFIER=1" "-PDATA_BINDING_VERSION=8.3.0"
Executing command: /Users/tsukasa/Desktop/GitHub/test-project/Temp/PlayServicesResolverGradle/gradlew --daemon -b "/Users/tsukasa/Desktop/GitHub/test-project/Temp/PlayServicesResolverGradle/PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" "-PANDROID_HOME=/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/6000.0.16f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=/Users/tsukasa/Desktop/GitHub/test-project/Assets/Plugins/Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=file:////Users/tsukasa/Desktop/GitHub/test-project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository;https://android-sdk.is.com/;https://maven.google.com/" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:0.11.01;com.ironsource:adqualitysdk:7.20.0;com.ironsource.unity:adqualitysdk:7.20.0;com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:8.3.0;com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1;com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0;com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.2.0;com.ironsource.adapters:admobadapter:4.3.44;com.ironsource.adapters:unityadsadapter:4.3.42;com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.12.2" "-PUSE_JETIFIER=1" "-PDATA_BINDING_VERSION=8.3.0"

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings_Decorated.
> Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

How ever if I copy the command from the window and run it directly in terminal, it works.
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :
ANDROID_HOME: /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/6000.0.16f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK
MAVEN_REPOS: name=Google url=https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/
MAVEN_REPOS: name=maven url=https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/
MAVEN_REPOS: name=maven2 url=https://maven.google.com/
MAVEN_REPOS: name=maven3 url=https://android-sdk.is.com/
MAVEN_REPOS: name=maven4 url=file:/Users/tsukasa/Desktop/GitHub/test-project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository/
MAVEN_REPOS: name=MavenLocal url=file:/Users/tsukasa/.m2/repository
MAVEN_REPOS: name=BintrayJCenter url=https://jcenter.bintray.com/
MAVEN_REPOS: name=MavenRepo url=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
PACKAGES_TO_COPY: com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:0.11.01
PACKAGES_TO_COPY: com.ironsource:adqualitysdk:7.20.0
PACKAGES_TO_COPY: com.ironsource.unity:adqualitysdk:7.20.0
PACKAGES_TO_COPY: com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:8.3.0
PACKAGES_TO_COPY: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1
PACKAGES_TO_COPY: com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0
PACKAGES_TO_COPY: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.2.0
PACKAGES_TO_COPY: com.ironsource.adapters:admobadapter:4.3.44
PACKAGES_TO_COPY: com.ironsource.adapters:unityadsadapter:4.3.42
PACKAGES_TO_COPY: com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.12.2
TARGET_DIR: /Users/tsukasa/Desktop/GitHub/test-project/Assets/Plugins/Android
Resolution attempt 1: packages [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1, com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:0.11.01, com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.2.0, com.ironsource.adapters:unityadsadapter:4.3.42, com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:8.3.0, com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.12.2, com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0, com.ironsource.unity:adqualitysdk:7.20.0, com.ironsource:adqualitysdk:7.20.0, com.ironsource.adapters:admobadapter:4.3.44]
Resolution attempt: 1, conflicts detected: false, updated packages: false
version locked packages: []
non-version locked packages: [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1, com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:0.11.01, com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.2.0, com.ironsource.adapters:unityadsadapter:4.3.42, com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:8.3.0, com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.12.2, com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0, com.ironsource.unity:adqualitysdk:7.20.0, com.ironsource:adqualitysdk:7.20.0, com.ironsource.adapters:admobadapter:4.3.44]

> Task :copy_androidx.annotation.annotation-1.6.0.jar
> Task :copy_androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.2.0.jar
> Task :copy_androidx.arch.core.core-runtime-2.2.0.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.browser.browser-1.4.0.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.collection.collection-1.1.0.jar
> Task :copy_androidx.core.core-1.9.0.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.customview.customview-1.0.0.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.fragment.fragment-1.1.0.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.interpolator.interpolator-1.0.0.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.6.1.jar
> Task :copy_androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-livedata-2.1.0.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-livedata-core-2.6.1.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-runtime-2.6.1.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-2.6.1.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.room.room-common-2.2.5.jar
> Task :copy_androidx.room.room-runtime-2.2.5.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.sqlite.sqlite-2.1.0.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.sqlite.sqlite-framework-2.1.0.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.versionedparcelable.versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.viewpager.viewpager-1.0.0.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.webkit.webkit-1.11.0-alpha02.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.work.work-runtime-2.7.0.aar
> Task :copy_androidx.work.work-runtime-ktx-2.7.0.aar
> Task :process_androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1.aar
> Task :process_androidx.activity.activity-ktx-1.7.1.aar
> Task :process_androidx.annotation.annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar
> Task :process_androidx.concurrent.concurrent-futures-1.1.0.jar
> Task :process_androidx.core.core-ktx-1.9.0.aar
> Task :process_androidx.datastore.datastore-1.0.0.aar
> Task :process_androidx.datastore.datastore-core-1.0.0.jar
> Task :process_androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-process-2.6.1.aar
> Task :process_androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-runtime-ktx-2.6.1.aar
> Task :process_androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-service-2.1.0.aar
> Task :process_androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.6.1.aar
> Task :process_androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate-2.6.1.aar
> Task :process_androidx.privacysandbox.ads.ads-adservices-1.0.0-beta05.aar
> Task :process_androidx.privacysandbox.ads.ads-adservices-java-1.0.0-beta05.aar
> Task :process_androidx.profileinstaller.profileinstaller-1.3.0.aar
> Task :process_androidx.savedstate.savedstate-1.2.1.aar
> Task :process_androidx.savedstate.savedstate-ktx-1.2.1.aar
> Task :process_androidx.startup.startup-runtime-1.1.1.aar
> Task :process_androidx.tracing.tracing-1.0.0.aar
> Task :process_com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-23.2.0.aar
> Task :process_com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-base-23.2.0.aar
> Task :process_com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-identifier-18.0.1.aar
> Task :process_com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-lite-23.2.0.aar
> Task :process_com.google.android.gms.play-services-appset-16.0.1.aar
> Task :process_com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-18.0.1.aar
> Task :process_com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-18.3.0.aar
> Task :process_com.google.android.gms.play-services-cronet-18.0.1.aar
> Task :process_com.google.android.gms.play-services-drive-17.0.0.aar
> Task :process_com.google.android.gms.play-services-games-v2-17.0.0.aar
> Task :process_com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2.aar
> Task :process_com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-sdk-api-20.1.2.aar
> Task :process_com.google.android.gms.play-services-nearby-18.0.2.aar
> Task :process_com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.1.0.aar
> Task :process_com.google.android.ump.user-messaging-platform-2.2.0.aar
> Task :process_com.google.code.findbugs.jsr305-3.0.2.jar
> Task :process_com.google.errorprone.error_prone_annotations-2.11.0.jar
> Task :process_com.google.games.gpgs-plugin-support-0.11.01.aar
> Task :process_com.google.guava.failureaccess-1.0.1.jar
> Task :process_com.google.guava.guava-31.1-android.jar
> Task :process_com.google.guava.listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar
> Task :process_com.google.j2objc.j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar
> Task :process_com.google.protobuf.protobuf-javalite-3.21.12.jar
> Task :process_com.google.protobuf.protobuf-kotlin-lite-3.21.12.jar
> Task :process_com.squareup.okhttp3.okhttp-3.12.13.jar
> Task :process_com.squareup.okio.okio-1.15.0.jar
> Task :process_org.checkerframework.checker-qual-3.12.0.jar
> Task :process_org.chromium.net.cronet-api-72.3626.96.aar
> Task :process_org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20.jar
> Task :process_org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.20.jar
> Task :process_org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.6.4.jar
> Task :process_org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.7.1.jar
> Task :process_org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.7.1.jar

> Task :copyPackages
Copied artifacts:
androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1.aar
androidx.activity.activity-ktx-1.7.1.aar
androidx.annotation.annotation-1.6.0.jar
androidx.annotation.annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar
androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.2.0.jar
androidx.arch.core.core-runtime-2.2.0.aar
androidx.browser.browser-1.4.0.aar
androidx.collection.collection-1.1.0.jar
androidx.concurrent.concurrent-futures-1.1.0.jar
androidx.core.core-1.9.0.aar
androidx.core.core-ktx-1.9.0.aar
androidx.customview.customview-1.0.0.aar
androidx.datastore.datastore-1.0.0.aar
androidx.datastore.datastore-core-1.0.0.jar
androidx.fragment.fragment-1.1.0.aar
androidx.interpolator.interpolator-1.0.0.aar
androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.6.1.jar
androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-livedata-2.1.0.aar
androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-livedata-core-2.6.1.aar
androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-process-2.6.1.aar
androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-runtime-2.6.1.aar
androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-runtime-ktx-2.6.1.aar
androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-service-2.1.0.aar
androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-2.6.1.aar
androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.6.1.aar
androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate-2.6.1.aar
androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0.aar
androidx.privacysandbox.ads.ads-adservices-1.0.0-beta05.aar
androidx.privacysandbox.ads.ads-adservices-java-1.0.0-beta05.aar
androidx.profileinstaller.profileinstaller-1.3.0.aar
androidx.room.room-common-2.2.5.jar
androidx.room.room-runtime-2.2.5.aar
androidx.savedstate.savedstate-1.2.1.aar
androidx.savedstate.savedstate-ktx-1.2.1.aar
androidx.sqlite.sqlite-2.1.0.aar
androidx.sqlite.sqlite-framework-2.1.0.aar
androidx.startup.startup-runtime-1.1.1.aar
androidx.tracing.tracing-1.0.0.aar
androidx.versionedparcelable.versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar
androidx.viewpager.viewpager-1.0.0.aar
androidx.webkit.webkit-1.11.0-alpha02.aar
androidx.work.work-runtime-2.7.0.aar
androidx.work.work-runtime-ktx-2.7.0.aar
com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-23.2.0.aar
com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-base-23.2.0.aar
com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-identifier-18.0.1.aar
com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-lite-23.2.0.aar
com.google.android.gms.play-services-appset-16.0.1.aar
com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-18.0.1.aar
com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-18.3.0.aar
com.google.android.gms.play-services-cronet-18.0.1.aar
com.google.android.gms.play-services-drive-17.0.0.aar
com.google.android.gms.play-services-games-v2-17.0.0.aar
com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2.aar
com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-sdk-api-20.1.2.aar
com.google.android.gms.play-services-nearby-18.0.2.aar
com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-18.1.0.aar
com.google.android.ump.user-messaging-platform-2.2.0.aar
com.google.code.findbugs.jsr305-3.0.2.jar
com.google.errorprone.error_prone_annotations-2.11.0.jar
com.google.games.gpgs-plugin-support-0.11.01.aar
com.google.guava.failureaccess-1.0.1.jar
com.google.guava.guava-31.1-android.jar
com.google.guava.listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar
com.google.j2objc.j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar
com.google.protobuf.protobuf-javalite-3.21.12.jar
com.google.protobuf.protobuf-kotlin-lite-3.21.12.jar
com.ironsource.adapters.admobadapter-4.3.44.aar
com.ironsource.adapters.unityadsadapter-4.3.42.aar
com.ironsource.adqualitysdk-7.20.0.aar
com.ironsource.sdk.mediationsdk-8.3.0.aar
com.ironsource.unity.adqualitysdk-7.20.0.aar
com.squareup.okhttp3.okhttp-3.12.13.jar
com.squareup.okio.okio-1.15.0.jar
com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.12.2.aar
org.checkerframework.checker-qual-3.12.0.jar
org.chromium.net.cronet-api-72.3626.96.aar
org.jetbrains.annotations-23.0.0.jar
org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20.jar
org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21.jar
org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.20.jar
org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.21.jar
org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.8.20.jar
org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.8.20.jar
org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.6.4.jar
org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.7.1.jar
org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.7.1.jar


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8s
77 actionable tasks: 77 executed

Doing this gives me a bunch of duplicate issues
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/6000.0.16f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/6000.0.16f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-8.4.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease" 

Environment Variables:
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_REDBUCKET_DEV = 46b8b46515e7632fc42a504b72e05fd0
DEBUG_ENV_VAR = UnityHub
XPC_FLAGS = 0x0
__CFBundleIdentifier = com.unity3d.unityhub
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_GREENBUCKET_DEV = 3ded2a762163603391a425f688f990c8
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_REDBUCKET_DEV = U4PSN7S7PuYVRODivvdcFwbu8R6IHGqa
COMMAND_MODE = unix2003
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_GREENBUCKET_PROD = c86fea37a9e1d3f0878b96e15b111c7c
SENTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 3df78d9e53f8456aa90fbae044ce1a6261421ab1d0014674bc2e933477289017
JAVA_HOME = /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/6000.0.16f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK
AMPLITUDE_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_RED_BUCKET_DEV = client-wbjHYrmeSR87GmWOE7LDpf7sUySOIKHm
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_GREENBUCKET_PROD = ZpUcbAdZXJYzNSoHsAWtL_s_JppwWid9
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY = 28f3cae0b33b8b3702120c9ed1a935aa
XPC_SERVICE_NAME = application.com.unity3d.unityhub.33918169.33918952
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/6000.0.16f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_STAGING = 83ee04fccc67e4fcc7dd527c4c6f1e21
WOOTRIC_CLIENT_TOKEN = NPS-aa8be4c3
USER = tsukasa
MallocNanoZone = 0
LOGNAME = tsukasa
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = 0x1F5:0x0:0x0
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_YELLOWBUCKET_DEV = 48835b4d1f5e342aefe5f016324d296a
PATH = /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Mw6RNio8ju/Listeners
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_YELLOWBUCKET_PROD = e03a9bbe92dc38a88cdb068d24c65b46
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_REDBUCKET_PROD = jTIgKs5KTZOjiqEEVdZFbgo_VRhABduL
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_YELLOWBUCKET_PROD = UYDQtPOw83dIfVy3SrW5oMyo7ru4PRkV
HOME = /Users/tsukasa
TMPDIR = /var/folders/9n/c5vjw6_x4cb9x55fks9ztc1m0000gn/T/
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_GREENBUCKET_DEV = 84H2gMm_FJzhr3mBaX1lM1JVukmCM7d9
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_YELLOWBUCKET_DEV = wKi8foVigDditGFvmZewRFWsEbX9Y0YO
SHELL = /bin/zsh
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_REDBUCKET_PROD = ca12bb461ea96f9bdf5df4ded7d52994
AMPLITUDE_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_RED_BUCKET_PROD = client-zH8Y7OK1i331EKuG77C6UxN8ygcM6LzS
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined


stderr[
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.RemoteActionCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.9.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.9.0:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.Cancellable found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$1 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2$1 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2$2 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$3 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$4 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$5 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$NonConfigurationInstances found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.ImmLeaksCleaner found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher$LifecycleOnBackPressedCancellable found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher$OnBackPressedCancellable found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcherOwner found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAware found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAwareHelper found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.contextaware.OnContextAvailableListener found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult$1 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCaller found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$1 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$2 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$3 found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$CallbackAndContract found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$LifecycleContainer found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistryOwner found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.IntentSenderRequest found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.IntentSenderRequest$Builder found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract$SynchronousResult found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$CreateDocument found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$GetContent found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$GetMultipleContents found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$OpenDocument found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$OpenDocumentTree found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$OpenMultipleDocuments found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
     Duplicate class androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$PickContact found in modules jetified-activity-1.2.3-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3) and jetified-androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1-runtime (:androidx.activity.activity-1.7.1:)
<message truncated>

If I delete everything from the plugin folder, it builds but on the device throws errors that it can't find the level play/ironsource files. Of course, they were deleted.
Checked the resolver settings and disabled Use Jetifier.
Run the command from terminal again since it fails from within the editor.
I try to build and run again and get the duplicate classes errors again.
